# How to input multiple variable values at the same time and print out the variables?

Tags: java

For example if I have the variables i = 1, love = 2, dogs = 3

I want to enter 1 2 3 to get the print line statement I love dogs

I hopping to get insight on how to go about doing this. The most important thing is that I need to enter all the values at the same time.

The only method I know is the SimpleInput class and i don't know if that class takes multiple inputs at the same time. Also I don't know how I can get the venerable to print out instead of the numbers.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Variable names (identifiers) should only be used to guide code development, not as values. This could be done via reflection, but I strongly recommend not doing so

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Map and store index as key and value as String that you want to consider.
Now whenever you are entering any value get the value from the map using
get() method of Map.

So your code would look something like this.

```
 Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
   map.put(1,"I");
   map.put(2,"Love");
   map.put(3,"Dogs");
```

For each input,get data from map.

```
 for(String arg:args) {
 System.out.print(map.get(arg));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple, name your variables "one, two, three" instead of 1, 2, 3. You cant name a variable a number. It would look something like this:

```
    String one = "I ";
    String two = "Love ";
    String three = "Dogs";

System.out.println(one + two + three);
```

//make sure to leave a space after each word, or alternatively if you don't want to you can add spaces manually in the print statement such as 
        System.out.println(one + " " + two + " " + three)

Comment: it has to be a number

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want is a method that can take in a number of strings and print them out in order. The values should be separated by spaces.

```
public static void print(String... strings) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (String string : strings) {
        if (result.length() != 0) {
            result.append(" ");
        }
        result.append(string);
    }
    System.out.println(result.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String one = "I";
    String two = "love";
    String three = "dogs";

    print(one, two, three);
}
```

This print method can accept any number of strings and output a well formatted line that contains all of the provided values.